# How do I find all heads that point to the same treeish

Tags: git, github

Let's say, for example, that I've got branches master, foo, and bar.

```
master
  \--foo
      |
     bar
```

foo and bar are the same thing. Imagine some work was committed on foo, then the user did `git checkout -b bar` but never did anything to bar. So, they both point to the same treeish.

Now, lets say time passes and I've forgotten what the name of that other branch was that was the same as foo, or maybe I just want to clean up my branches.

**What command do I need to execute when on the foo branch, to see all the other branches that point to the same treeish (in this case just bar)?**

How / why is this useful? Well, since pull requests on Github are branches that can be tracked, I can look at an old branch I have sitting around, run this command, and have it show me `origin/pr/42` and now I have the id of the old pull request (42) to go look at it on Github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A git idiomatic way is to use `for-each-ref` with `rev-parse` to find all the references that share the tree-ish. For instance, assuming bash as the shell:

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" | \
xargs -I refname \
  sh -c '[[ $(git rev-parse HEAD^{tree}) == $(git rev-parse refname^{tree}) ]] && echo refname'
```

This will list all the refs, including remote refs that share the tree-ish.

Here’s a sample output:

```
$ git branch foo
$ git for-e...
refs/heads/foo
refs/heads/master
refs/remotes/origin/master
$ git checkout foo
$ git branch bar
$ git for-e...
refs/heads/bar
refs/heads/foo
refs/heads/master
refs/remotes/origin/master
$ echo “new content” >> README && git add README && git commit –m “New tree-ish”
$ git for-e...
refs/heads/foo
```

Comment: This works, and I'm accepting it as the answer, but I'd love it if you could explain why it's `HEAD^{tree}` and `refname^{tree}` When I started reading it I was expecting it to be comparing `rev-parse HEAD` to `rev-parse refname`. What's the advantage to your comparison?

Comment: Git references can be tags, and otherwise point to commits. You are not interested in the commit but rather dereferencing the commit object until you reach the relevant treeish - the difference can be illustrated if you run `git show HEAD` and `git show HEAD^{tree}` for example.

Answer (score 1):

```
git log --all --simplify-by-decoration --pretty=format:'%T %h %d %s' \
| awk '
     $3~/,/        { seen[$1]=2 }         # late addition to handle same-commit refs
     ++seen[$1]==1 { save[$1]=$0; next }
       seen[$1]==2 { print save[$1] }
                   { print }
'
```

Comment: Probably should allow for >= 2 in case there are more than two labels/commits ultimately pointing to the same tree.

Comment: @torek Did I miss something?  I think the ==2 part prints the first one when the dup is detected, the unconditional prints all the rest.

Comment: @torek ah, okay, I get it -- it's two refs pointing to the same _commit_ that it didn't handle, I got the hard part right, except it turns out the hard part for me was also getting the easy part right :-)

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't something fancy but I would get the hash for the commit I'm currently on
like this for example

```
git log -1 --oneline
```

then take the hash and do

```
git branch --all --contains [hash]
```

Comment: Not quite the same thing. I don't want all branches that CONTAIN the hash, I want all branches whose head IS that hash.